# Fancybox loading the whole page in the box instead of text div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, fancybox

I am having an issue with fancybox-rails.

Basically, i want to have a clickable image. When i click on it, a fancybox opens with some information about the image...

The issue i am having is that, the first click, nothing happens, the second, the text appears in the fancybox (as the specifications). The third, it opens a fancybox with the whole page loaded on it !!

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="#data-1" data-fancybox="#data-1" id="info-1">
  <img alt="Some image info" src="the_image.JPG"></a>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="data-1">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

My jQuery code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[data-fancybox]").click(function(){
  $(this).fancybox();
  });
});
```

Do you see anything obvious in the code that could explain this behaviour ?

Thanks!

P.S: Versions are fancybox-1, ruby-on-rails-4

Answer (score 3):

In your Javascript file, (ex. **app/assets/javascripts/posts.js**):

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    'content': $('#data-1')
  });

};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

The surrounding "document ready" code plays nice with [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/), which is enabled by default in Rails 4.

**NOTE:** I believe that **fancybox** has a bug in it and this solution is a hackish workaround that doesn't trigger the bug. The [API docs](http://fancybox.net/api) states that the *content* attribute "Forces content (can be any html data)."

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[data-fancybox]").click(function(){
      $(this).fancybox();
  });
});
```

... is that it doesn't trigger fancybox on `click`, it only binds `[data-fancybox]`  to fancybox after the first `click`, but still needs a second `click` to fire fancybox.

You actually only need to do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox();
});
```

and the `[data-fancybox]` element will be bound to fancybox, and fancybox will handle any `click` event afterwards.

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HeAR7/)</kbd>